# Jquery, JSON, Cakephp Question Autoloader UI

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, autocomplete

Been trying to get this to work all day. Had a look on net for fix still no luck. So i bring it to you :). Basically got 4 files - autocomplete controller, autocomplete.js, autocomplete.css, default.ctp.

Got this from tutorial and tried to basically modify. basically what i want it to do is as the user starts typing in the search box it shows retailers or vouchers depending on what the dropdown is set to. At the moment just focusing on retailers as not sure on how i can do the other bit yet lol.

autocomplete controller:

```
> class AutocompleteController extends
> AppController {   var $name =
> 'Autocompletes';  var $helpers =
> array('Ajax', 'Javascript');  var
> $components = array('RequestHandler');
>   var $layout = 'default';    var
> $uses=array('Retailer','Voucher');
> 
>   function home(){    }
> 
>   function search(){      if (
> $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() ) {
>               Configure::write ( 'debug', 1 );
>               $this->autoRender=false;            $query = $_GET['term'];
>           $retailers=$this->Retailer->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Retailer.title
> LIKE'=>'%'.$query.'%')));
>               $i=0;
>               foreach($retailers as $retailer){
>                   $response[$i]['value']=$retailer['Retailer']['title'];
>                   $response[$i]['label']="<span class=\"username\">".$retailer['Retailer']['title']."</span>";
>               $i++;
>               }           echo json_encode($response);        }else{          if (!empty($this->data)) {
>               $this->set('Retailers',$this->paginate(array('Retailer.title
> LIKE'=>'%'.$this->data['Retailer']['title'].'%')));
>           }       }   } }
```

autocomplete.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Caching the movieName textbox:
var username = $('.search-text-field');

// Defining a placeholder text:
username.defaultText('Search for retailers');

// Using jQuery UI's autocomplete widget:
username.autocomplete({
minLength    : 1,
source        : 'autocomplete/search'
});

});

// A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

$.fn.defaultText = function(value){

var element = this.eq(0);
element.data('defaultText',value);

element.focus(function(){
if(element.val() == value){
element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
}
}).blur(function(){
if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){
element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
}
});

return element.blur();
}
```

autocomplete.css

```
.search-text-field{
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 380px;
    border: 2px solid #ff2f2f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Styling the markup generated by the autocomplete jQuery UI widget */

ul.ui-autocomplete{
    width:250px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-top:-4px;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
}

ul.ui-autocomplete li{
    list-style:none;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-left:1px solid white;
    margin:0;
}

ul.ui-autocomplete li:first-child{
    border-top:none;
}

ul.ui-autocomplete li:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}

ul.ui-autocomplete li a{
    border:none !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    padding:2px;
    display:block;
    color:black;
}
ul.ui-autocomplete li img{
    margin-right:4px;
}
ul.ui-autocomplete li span{
}

#ui-active-menuitem{
    background-color:#efefef;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

default.ctp

```
<head>

<?php echo $javascript->link("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");?>
    <?php echo $javascript->link('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js');?>
    <script src="http://htm5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <?php echo $html->css("/css/autocomplete.css"); ?>
    <?php echo $javascript->link("/js/autocomplete.js");?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="search">         
    <?php echo $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'autocomplete', 'action'=>'search'), array('return')); ?>
</div> 
</body>...
```

I guess i should show the few for autocomplete search aswell...

```
<?php echo $form->create('Search', array('action'=>'search'));?>

<div class="seatext">
    <?php echo __('Search Amazing Voucher Codes',true); ?>
</div>
<div class="seadd">
    <?php
    $options = array('retailers'=>__('Retailer',true), 'vouchers'=>__('Voucher',true));
    echo $form->select('search_type', $options, null, array('class'=>'search-dropdown'), false);?>
</div>
<div class="seabox">
    <?php echo $form->input('search_data', array('title'=>'', 'class'=>'search-text-field', 'size'=>30, 'label'=>false, 'div'=>false)); ?>
</div>
<div class="search_but">
    <?php echo $form->end( array('label'=>__('Search',true),'div'=>false,'class'=>'search-button'));?>
</div>
```

At the moment when I type nothing happens however when i search it brings up results on a results page.

If you need any mroe info i can supply thanks in advance. Thanks
Chris

Comment: Your real controller file doesn't contain the chevrons does it?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that the source url is valid 'autocomplete/search' is not the same as '/autocomplete/search' (which you might need).
- Be mindful of the field that the ajax is GET'ing. The script is looking for $_GET['term']. yet I don't see that field name is the input.search-text-field.
- I would use Firebug to look at the ajax data that is being sent. This is an invaluable tool in these situations.